# Can you open a form or window in an Outlook Addin (VSTO)

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2007

I am new to VSTO programming. I have created a basic addin for Outlook 2007 that monitors a folder containing XML text files which it opens and then sends them as an email, then deletes them. this all works fine.

I want the user to be able to configure certain settings for the way the addin/program will operate, such as the folder that it will monitor, and other things. The logical way to do this is to create a menu item in the addin (which I have also done) that opens a windows form (or XAML window) that allows them to enter the parameters.

In my addin I added a new item Windows Form, which worked, and the designer opened. However, in my addin code I cannot open the form. The Show() method normally associated with form objects is not available.

Is this simply something you cannot do, or am I just doing it the wrong way?

I have read about Outlook form regions, but these seemed to be attached to outlook items such as a new email, task, appointment etc... there doesnt seem to be a way to create a form region that can be opened in the main window of Outlook.

Ideally, I would like to go with my original method of opening a new window from a menu item, but if this isnt possible I would like to hear other solutions.

Thanks,
Will.

Comment: You can open windows just fine. What do you mean it's "not available"? Do you get an error when trying to open it or what? If you get an error (runtime or compile-time) then please post the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a normal form, it sounds like you didn't just add System.Windows.Forms as a reference, 
create the object then show it eg.

```
Form myFrm = new frmFlightList();
myFrm.Show();
```

This should work in a VSTO addin, as it does in any other form. The CMSConnectorControl object you refer to is a distraction to others for the general case of just wanting to display a form.

Comment: this code causes this: this activex controls  can not instantiated beacause current thread is not a single-threaded apartment.

Answer (score 0):

figured this out, After I built my form I just had to add these lines

```
CMSConnectorControl formMain = new CMSConnectorControl();
formMain.ShowDialog();
```

to the ThisAddin_Startup() function.